# What would be an avg schema creation time for AppSync schema's via aws-cli

Tags: aws-cli, aws-appsync

Using the AWS CLI command

```
aws appsync start-schema-creation --api-id <your-api-id> --definition file://<file-path>
```

after the first time it returns

```
{
  "status": "PROCESSING"
}
```

This has been going on for a while (around 30 minutes) for a 4kb Schema. Any reasonable way to estimate how long it takes or what factors affect the time (e.g. Number of attributes in an object, or amount of fields on a mutation).

Comment: It should just me a minute or less. If you're getting this much time you should open up a ticket with AWS support through the console.

Comment: it hangs, the schema is invalid, i had to put it manually in the aws console to find out, i'm still figuring out a way to lint the thing